# SPSiteDataQuery to Search both Lists and Libraries

Tags: 2013, list, search, library, spsitedataquery

I have a SPSiteDataQuery that I am giving a set of list ID's.  The set of lists are both Generic Lists & also Libraries.  The issue is my Libraries are not being returned.  Is it possible to search both Lists & Libraries with SPSiteDataQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can only query a specific type of list. SPSiteDataQuery use the template id to return the rows. so for document library data, you need to add another query for that.